# Is there a Win10 cloning tool for Android devices?

Tags: rom-flashing, flashtool, virtualization

I am looking for a cloning tool similar to Macrium for Win10, that is capable of cloning Android devices to a runnable virtual machine image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically possible but unlikely that you be able (or want) to do this in reality because of the following problems:

1. Cloning of a device is not possible unless it is rooted (and even then some keys can't be extracted because they are protected in the ARM TrustZone).
2. Android devices have an ARM CPU, PCs usually an x86 CPU, which means the PC would have to emulate an ARM CPU which is very CPU intensive and thus the emulated Android will be slow even if you use a high-end CPU.
3. An Android firmware is not universal, it is developed to target one specific hardware (display, touch digitizer, Wifi chip, System-SoC, ,...), so you would need an emulator that emulates exactly your hardware. It is unlikely that you find such an emulator.